# Map.fromIterable specify argument type of key/value extraction lambdas

Tags: dart

Given this code:

```
class Dog{
  String name = "Dog";
  int age = 2;
}

final list = [Dog(), Dog()]

final dogNameToAge = Map.fromIterable(
  list, key: (value)=> value.name, value: (value)=>value.age)
```

Type of 'key' lambda is `String Function(dynamic)?` is there a way  of using something more like: `String Function(Dog)?` so that it would be more type safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that constructor is cursed since it does not have any concept of generics. I would do the following instead (fixed `age` so it is not assigned to `"2"` but `2`:

```dart
class Dog {
  String name = "Dog";
  int age = 2;
}

final list = [Dog(), Dog()];

final dogNameToAge = Map.fromEntries(list.map((e) => MapEntry(e.name, e.age)));
```

The type of `dogNameToAge` is then `Map<String, int>` as expected.

Or do what @lrn suggests. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also write it using a map literal:

```dart
final dogNameToAge = {for (var dog in list) dog.name: dog.age};
```

That's my recommendation over `fromIterables` any day.